# Client CXF IllegalArgumentException XMLGregorianCalendarImpl dateTime

Tags: java, spring, web-services, client, cxf

I have a problem consuming a web service with CXF 2.7.7 on Java 1.6

The error says:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl$Parser.parseAndSetYear(XMLGregorianCalendarImpl.java:2850)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl$Parser.parse(XMLGregorianCalendarImpl.java:2737)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl.<init>(XMLGregorianCalendarImpl.java:433)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl.newXMLGregorianCalendar(DatatypeFactoryImpl.java:532)
at  com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl$12.parse(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:479)
```

I think the problem is related to the elements of type dateTime in the XSD of WSDL

```
<element name="audFecCreac" type="dateTime" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" />
```

With SOAPUI i see

```
 <audFecCreac>2013-10-07T14:37:19.000-03:00</audFecCreac>
```

I created the client with wsdl2java command line on java 1.6

```
wsdl2java -d D:\mysource -frontend jaxws21 -b bindings.txt http://myserver:8011/myservice?wsdl
```

and compiled with maven with this dependencies (to make a jar)

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

And the bindings.txt file

```
<jaxb:bindings version="2.1" 
  xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" 
  xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"> 
    <jaxb:globalBindings generateElementProperty="false"/> 
</jaxb:bindings>
```

I implement the client with Spring 3.2.4.RELEASE

```
    <bean id="myWS" class="my.package.InterfaceEndpoint" factory-bean="myWSFactory" factory-method="create"/>
<bean id="myWSFactory" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean">
     <property name="serviceClass" value="my.package.InterfaceEndpoint"/>
     <property name="address" value="http://myserver:8011/myservice?wsdl"/>
</bean>
```

Thanks for any response